# why cryptojs.enc.Base64.parse different length text can get result of the same (byte) length?

Tags: python, cryptojs, 3des

here:

```
CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('3DJ3XmbByr2y6w1113159151954972672')
CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('3DJ3XmbByr2y6w1113159151954972672').toString()
CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('3DJ3XmbByr2y6w1113159151954972672').toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pj4gC.png)

```
CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('3DJ3XmbByr2y6w111315915195497267')
CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('3DJ3XmbByr2y6w111315915195497267').toString()
CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('3DJ3XmbByr2y6w111315915195497267').toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)
```

[run results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qQgm.png)

the return is the same 24 byte length object WordArray but the input is different length .

why?

```
function encryptByTripleDES(msg, key) {
    const keyHex = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key)
    const encrypted = CryptoJS.TripleDES.encrypt(msg, keyHex, {
      mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
      padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    })
    return encrypted.toString()
  }
```

here is the 3des achive of cryptojs. when the length of inputted key is 33 like '3DJ3XmbByr2y6w1113159151954972672', it works. when i use this key to do 3des encrypt in python,it will doesn't work( the key length is wrong)
how to implements in python?

```
def encrypt_by_triple_des(data:str, key):
    key_bytes = base64.b64decode(key)
    msg_bytes = data.encode('utf-8')
    cipher = DES3.new(key_bytes, DES3.MODE_ECB)
    padded_msg = pad(msg_bytes, DES3.block_size)
    encrypted_msg = cipher.encrypt(padded_msg)
    return base64.b64encode(encrypted_msg).decode('utf-8')
```

if the length of key satisfied 32,it works . in this case, some key can work in cryptojs but not in python.

Comment: _when i use this key to do 3des encrypt in python,it will doesn't work( the key length is wrong)_ Can you share your python snippets that do not work?

Comment: [`CryptoJS.enc.Base64`](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#encoders) is the Base64 encoder of CryptoJS. With `parse()` a Base64 string is converted into a `WordArray`. However, `3DJ3XmbByr2y6w1113159151954972672` (unlike `3DJ3XmbByr2y6w111315915195497267`) is *not a valid* Base64 string, since the length of a valid Base64 string is always a multiple of 4 (see [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)). So Python rightly complains about the data, while CryptoJS corrects internally (which is intransparent and misleading).